# Does web.py support search box? Like the search bar on the top right of stack overflow?

Tags: python, web.py

I'm new to web.py and front end.

The problem is that I didn't find any search box support in web.py cookbook. I did some research and it seems that web.py form only supports Textbox, Password, Textarea, Dropdown, Radio, Checkbox, Button.

I wonder if I can use form to add a search box like the right top of stackoverflow.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A "search box" is just a text input hooked up to a search function.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://kooneiform.wordpress.com/2010/02/28/python-and-ajax-for-beginners-with-webpy-and-jquery/)

Comment: Search box is not a base type!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that I didn't make it clear. What I was wondering is that to define a form inside python script and render it in .html, so that the search box layout would be generated like this:
[image]. 
For example, we can define a form like the following:

```
<pre>
  <code>
    register_form = form.Form(
        form.Textbox("username", description="Username"),
        form.Textbox("email", vemail, description="E-Mail"),
        form.Password("password", vpass, description="Password"),
        form.Password("password2", description="Repeat password"),
        form.Button("submit", type="submit", description="Register"),
    )
  </code>
</pre>
```

but I didn't find any built in class for searchBox, something like web.form.SearchBox("..."), in which we can set the placeholder of the search box.

I solved the problem by defining the layout with html and bound the search box with a function, just like Henry's advice.

Again thanks for responses. Was confused at the beginning.